# EntityFramework, services and transactions

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-6

I'm currently using EF6 and a service pattern for business rules. I have the need for transactions. Unfortunally, I'm don't have the deep knowledge about how EF manages transcations. Please look at the code below:

```
public class Service1
{
    private DbContext context;
    private string connectionString = "yada, yada, yada";
    public Service1()
    {
        context = new DbContext(connectionString); //DbContext is IRL a 
        context from an EF-dbfirst project, this is only for illustration
    }

    public void SaveStuff(object stuff)
    {
        var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction();
        try
        {
            var s2 = new Service2();
            context.[DbEntity].Add(stuff);
            s2.SaveOtherStuff("stuff");
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
    }
}

public class Service2
{
    private DbContext context;
    private string connectionString = "yada, yada, yada";
    public Service2()
    {
        context = new DbContext(connectionString);
    }

    public void SaveOtherStuff(object stuff)
    {
        context.[DbEntity].Add(stuff);
    }
}
```

The transaction is created with Service1 context object. Will the transaction follow to the Service2 or is Service2 using a context object without any knowledge of the ongoing transaction? Do I need to pass the context object owning the transaction to Service2 in some way (contructor)?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, this all seems like a bad design.

**Some notes** : You should not really be creating and holding on to `DbContexts` or `Transactions`, both should be `Disposed` in a `using` statement ideally

However, i believe  you can use the same `Transaction` for multiple `DBContexts`, though i think this might be dependent on SqlServer version and if the databases lives in the same SqlServer "Dont quote me on that"

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())  
{  
    using (myContext context = new myContext())  
    {  
        Test t = new Test()  
         t.Name="TEST";
         context.AddToTests(t);  
         context.SaveChanges();  
    }  

    using (myContext context = new myContext())  
    {                       
         Demo d = context.Demos.First(s => s.Name == "Demo1");  
         context.DeleteObject(d);  
         context.SaveChanges();  
    }  

    scope.Complete();  

   // also make sure you add error checking and rollback
}
```

Lastly, Having the same contexts over different Service calls just seems wrong, you do not need to cache a `DBContext`, `EF` does this job extremely well behind the scenes

**Update**

I just noticed you create a new `DBContext` per service. anyway use a `using` statement for both `DbContext` and `Transaction` or risk being vilified by your colleagues :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you need to instantiate two dbcontext but if you share the same dbcontext through the services you don't need to work with explicit transaction (.SaveChanges() creates a sql transaction itself) then pass the dbContext to the Service2 in the constructor.

If you want to work with two different dbContext you can share only the transaction and the connection of the first dbContext, then:

```
public void SaveStuff(object stuff)
{
   using(var transaction = context.Database.BeginTransaction())
   {
        try
        {
            var s2 = new Service2(transaction, context.Database.Connection);
            context.[DbEntity].Add(stuff);
            s2.SaveOtherStuff("stuff");
            context.SaveChanges();
            transaction.Commit();
        }
        catch
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
   }
}


public class Service2
{
    private DbContext context;
    public Service2(DbContextTransaction transaction, DbConnection connection)
    {
        context = new DbContext(connection, false);
        context.Database.UseTransaction(transaction);
    }

    public void SaveOtherStuff(object stuff)
    {
        context.[DbEntity].Add(stuff);
    }
}
```